# Using brackets and ? in Android SQLiteDatabase query()

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to execute a query on a SQLiteDatabase in Android, using the query() function. I want to pass the argument in SelectionArgs[], but when I'm using a IN statement, it doesn't seem to substitute the '?' with the correct argument.

My query looks like this:

```
temp = database.query(TABLE_NAME_ENTRIES, 
                new String[] {"_id", "Entry", "Summary"}, 
                "_id IN ( ? )",
                new String[] {ids}, null, null, null);
```

and it results in an empty Cursor. Debug gives me the information that the executed query uses a statement "_id IN ( ? )", showing that it doesn't seem to replace the '?' as expected. When I change the query to

```
temp = database.query(TABLE_NAME_ENTRIES, 
                new String[] {"_id", "Entry", "Summary"}, 
                "_id IN ( " + ids + " )",
                null, null, null, null);
```

instead, I get the expected result.

I'm really stupid on this problem, any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `ids`?

Comment: its a String, like "192,123,23,13"

Comment: That needs to be split out into an array that you pass as the 4th argument, with a `?` for each index in the 3rd (the selection String). If it's always going to be 4 ids, you can just hard code the selection String. Otherwise, you can use something like Gabriella's `makePlaceholders()` method to generate it.

Comment: I need only one '?'
The query I would like to do is WHERE _id IN ( 192,123,23,13 ), so I basically just want to put the whole String ids where I have the '?' now.

Comment: "I need only one '?'" - Nope, you need 4. When you use _selectionArgs_, each value in the array is quoted when it's substituted for a `?`, so after building the query as is, it would end up like `WHERE _id IN ( '192,123,23,13' )`, which has only one value in the `IN` clause.

Comment: Or, you could just create the whole query String yourself, and use `rawQuery()`, as Gabriella also demonstrates, but substituting `ids` for the `makePlaceholders()` call.

Comment: "Or, you could just create the whole query String yourself, and use rawQuery(), as Gabriella also demonstrates, but substituting ids for the makePlaceholders() call." 
Yes, I'm actually doing this in the second example, but using the regular query(). That's why it took me so long to find my mistake.

Comment: Oops, just noticed, that should have ended "...and passing null for the second argument." Anywho, glad you got it figured out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a workaround like this - creating a method that generates dynamically your string with `?` and `,` and put it in the query like this:

```
String[] ids = { "id1", "id2" }; // do whatever is needed first
String query = "SELECT * FROM table"
+ " WHERE _id IN (" + makePlaceholders(ids.length) + ")";
Cursor cursor = mDb.rawQuery(query, ids);


String makePlaceholders(int len) {
    if (len < 1) {
        // It will lead to an invalid query anyway ..
       throw new RuntimeException("No placeholders");
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len * 2 - 1);
        sb.append("?");
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            sb.append(",?");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

P.S. I think that the spaces before and after the question mark in your query could be wrong there, but I didn't test it, so I can't be 100% sure

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't explain correctly. ids is already a string, prepared to be inserted instead of the '?'. Basically, all I want to do is to replace the '?' by the value of ids.
I tried eliminating the spaces, with no change